# Identifying which element invoked the event

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have following html code

```
<input type="button"  id ="b1" value="Click me" onclick="msg()" />
<input type="button" id="b2"   value="Click me" onclick="msg()" />
```

now in my javascript i want to identify whether button one was clicked or button 2. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your inline handler to use the `.call()` method, setting the context of the function to `this`:

```
<input type="button"  id ="b1" value="Click me" onclick="msg.call( this )" />
```

...then in your function, `this` will represent the one that received the event.

```
function msg() {
    alert( this.id );
}
```

---

Otherwise, you could pass `this` as an argument:

```
<input type="button"  id ="b1" value="Click me" onclick="msg( this )" />
```

...and reference that argument:

```
function msg( elem ) {
    alert( elem.id );
}
```

Comment: i canntot pass this, am using dojoattachevent to associate event with a event handler

Comment: @akshay: Then use the first example, which doesn't pass `this`. You should be able to pass the `event` by doing `onclick="msg.call( this, event )"`.

Comment: @akshay - surely dojo proxies either the event or the element as the context already?

Answer (score 1):

Have your msg() function take in an object.  Then when you call it, pass in

```
msg(this);
```

Comment: inside msg function how can i identify if button 1/2 was clicked?

Comment: if your parameter name is o, do o.id

Comment: You are much faster than me @subhaze  Thank you

Comment: i am using dojoAttachevent to associate eventhandler with event, so i think i cant passs this

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix JavaScript directly into your HTML with JavaScript attributes such as `onclick`. You should instead programmatically attach your handlers using JavaScript. At the simplest:

```
function msg = function( evt ){
  // For old IE versions that don't pass in the event, 
  // get the global event object.
  if (!evt) evt = window.event;

  // Use currentTarget if available, target if not,
  // and srcElement for old versions of IE
  var receiver = evt.currentTarget || evt.target || evt.srcElement;

  alert( receiver.id );
};
document.getElementById('b1').onclick = msg;
```

Event handlers are passed an event object as their first parameter (except for very old IE versions, which set a global `event` property).

The difference between the `currentTarget` and `target` properties has to do with event bubbling. If an event occurs on a child element, but then bubbles up to some ancestor that has a handler for that event, the `currentTarget` property is the child element and the `target` property is the ancestor that has the event handler.

Old versions of IE do not have `currentTarget` or `target` properties, but instead use `srcElement` to mean the same thing as `target`.

Now, if you are attaching your event handlers in code to elements directly (not using bubbling), you already (at one point) have a reference to the element. So here's the alternative, more-advanced-but-simpler method:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0,len=inputs.length;i<len;++i){
  if (inputs[i].type=='button'){
    inputs[i].onclick = (function(i){
      return function(){
        alert(inputs[i].id);
      }
    })(i);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From reading answers/comments I find that you're using dojo. You could reference it via the event object. I've only tested this in chrome,FF, and ie8 but this seemed to work:

```
templateString: "<div>" + '<button id="button1" dojoAttachEvent="onclick: msg">press me1</button><button id="button2" dojoAttachEvent="onclick: msg">press me2</button></div>',
msg:function(e){
    alert(e.currentTarget.id);   
}
```

**[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/2jbxR/4/)**

Comment: it's not necessary to use Dojo templates.  You can just use the event argument for HTML's onclick, even if you're using Dojo.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Dojo, but it seemed if the OP was using `dojoAttachEvent` that the template system was being used. So I used this as a way to demonstrate.